How to make large list of properties(@api or @track decorated) more decluttered and organized in your LWC JavaScript file?
I have more than 30 properties in LWC JS file. few of them are @api decorated. Is there any way to group them together for better code readability or place them in helper JS?
Thanks in Advance.

You can put the tracked properties into an object. See the docs and read the section "Observe an Object’s Properties or an Array’s Elements".
